# Marshalling /Pinvoking function pointers containing structures

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke, function-pointers, marshalling

I want to use this C code in a wrapper class in C#. I have a strucutre with various parameters, including a struct and function pointers.

C Code:

```
struct wiringPiNodeStruct
{
  int     pinBase ;
  int     pinMax ;

  int          fd ; // Node specific
  unsigned int data0 ;  //  ditto

  void   (*pinMode)         (struct wiringPiNodeStruct *node, int pin, int mode) ;

  struct wiringPiNodeStruct *next ;
} ;
```

I tried marshalling the above code. But I am unable to find proper solutions for function pointers containing structures and a struct within a struct.

C# Code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct wiringPiNodeStruct
{
    public int pinBase;
    public int pinMax;

    public int fd; // Node specific
    public uint data0; //  ditto


    public delegate void pinMode (struct wiringPiNodeStruct IntPtr node, int pin, int mode) ;

    public struct wiringPiNodeStruct *next ;
};
```

Comment: Linked lists are tricky. Going to be a world of pain in p/invoke. Of course we have absolutely no idea what your problem is. You are marshalling from manager to unmanaged, or the other way. You don't know how to populate this linked list from managed code. Or you don't know how to walk such a list that was populated in unmanaged code. Realistically you'd find it a lot easier to do this from C++/CLI. Now, a question for you. Please don't ignore this question. Have you ever coded linked lists in C or C++? I ask because if you have not then you have little hope. Don't run before you can walk.

Comment: I am quite new to C#. And the terms managed and marshalling are new too. I am creating a wrapper class in C# for fucntions which uses this structure. I want to use the above structure in C#. i.e. I want to recreate the struct on the .net side and then let marshalling handle converting the memory between .net and c. No I have not coded linkedlists,

Comment: That is going to be rather arduous. I suspect that attempting something this advanced given your level of experience is not going to be productive. If I were your supervisor I would advise you to write some example code in C++ to get a feel for this library and how to work with linked lists. Linked lists are quite tricky if you've never seen them before. And to attempt to learn them with the complication of p/invoke getting in the way is just not at all productive in my view. You will waste huge amounts of time going it that way.

Comment: Ok. But is there a way where I can recreate a class (similar to the struct in C) in C# and map them? Will it work?

Comment: Of course it can be done. But it's not easy. Doubly so if you have no experience of linked lists. I've said all I want to here. Take my advice, or don't. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter, whether you used linked lists before, or not... what you have here is just a structure having a field pointing to it´s "successor". Of course, I cannot guarantee that the solution I´d like to suggest will work without modification; but I have worked with P/Invoke quite a lot, so I would try something like that... at least, it will give you an idea, hopefully.

For the sake of simplicity (and taking out some Marshalling magic) I would declare the `pinMode` and `next` as `IntPtr` fields; keep in mind that `IntPtr` has a different size in 32- and 64 bit. Make sure that the managed and unmanaged parts use the same bitness...

```
delegate void pinMode (IntPtr node, int pin, int mode);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct wiringPiNodeStruct
{
    public int pinBase;
    public int pinMax;
    public int fd;
    public uint data0;
    public IntPtr pinMode;
    public IntPtr next
};
```

You may face two scenarios; you either just need to read and process the structure(s), or you want to create and pass it to unmanaged code. Let´s look at the reading part; iterating the list could look like that...

```
wiringPiNodeStruct node = ...
while (node.next != IntPtr.Zero) 
{
    wiringPiNodeStruct next;
    next = (wiringPiNodeStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        node.next, 
        typeof(wiringPiNodeStruct));

    ...

    node = next;
}
```

If you want/need to call the `pinMode` function, you could try something like that...

```
wiringPiNodeStruct node = ...
wiringPiNodeStruct next = (wiringPiNodeStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(
    node.next, 
    typeof(wiringPiNodeStruct));

pinMode func = (pinMode) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
    next.pinMode, 
    typeof(pinMode));

func(node.next, 0, 0);
```

Now let´s create a structure; this is of course a super-trivial example... you may create some helper utilities that can create the linked list structure from an enumerable data source - and also keeps track of allocated memory and properly releases unmanaged memory when no longer needed.

```
var second = new wiringPiNodeStruct { };

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(wiringPiNodeStruct));
IntPtr pSecond = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(second, pSecond, true);

pinMode func = new pinMode((ptr, pin, mode) => { });

var first = new wiringPiNodeStruct { };
first.pinMode = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(func);
first.next = pSecond;
```

If `pinMode` is used as a callback by the unmanaged part, make sure that the `func` has the same lifetime as the pointer that is stored in the `pinMode` field.

You could also play, with different declarations of the `wiringPiNodeStruct` type; sometimes it´s easier to have declarations that are tailored for reading or writing...